# Retrieving images from MySQL DB and saving to server directory using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm looking for a way to save images stored in a MySQL database on a different server to a directory on the server I'm currently working with. I'm retrieving JSON data, and each entry displays a url that links directly to the image **stored in the database**. This is what I'm doing currently, with no success.

```
<?php
   $url = 'https://secure.example.com/app/api?accountid=000&apikey=000&action=getview&format=json&viewid=0000&tableid=0000';

   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

  $imageList = json_decode($response,true);

  $x = 1;

  foreach ($imageList as $imageItem) {
     $img = $imageItem['face_image'];

     echo "<img src='" . $img . "' width='150' height='200'/>"; //THIS WORKS, DISPLAYS IMAGES

     $dest_dir = "/uploads/"; //THIS DIRECTORY IS 777 CURRENTLY
     $src_file = $img;

     file_put_contents($dest_dir.$x.".jpg", $src_file);

     $x++;
}?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desitination seems suspect: `$dest_dir = "/uploads/"` This means the root of the server ie. where `bin`,`lib`, etc. live, as opposed to the webserver's DOCUMENT_ROOT. You probably dont have permission to write there. Try:

`$dest_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/"`